# Recommended practice for restricting ImagerResizer module to just one specific route/sub-directory?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, imageresizer

What is the recommended practice for restricting ImageResizer to only act on images within a specified sub-directory (in my personal case requiring watermarks only on images within a certain directory via PostRewrite, but apart from a couple sub-directories, I really don't want site-wide images even touching the InterceptModule if I don't have to)?

- Configure ignore routes somehow via MvcRoutingShim [as referenced without an example in ImageResizer.net documentation](http://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/plugins/mvcroutingshim).
- `<location ...>` in Web.config:

  `<location path="some-path/some-directory" inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpModules>
        <add name="ImageResizingModule" type="ImageResizer.InterceptModule"/>
      </httpModules>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>`
- Application.BeginRequest filter out on path.
- Or really late filter on PostRewrite (Config.Current.Pipleline.PostRewrite).
- Or?

Details:

- ASP.NET MVC 5.2.3 (Integrated)
- ImageResizer 4.x
- IIS 7 (Windows Server 2008 R2)

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33440702/configuring-imageresizer-web-config-to-only-work-on-certain-directories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle `Config.Current.PostRewrite` and set `process=no` and `cache=no` in the event parameters (querystring). This will disable ImageResizer interaction with the request.

As mentioned in [Configuring ImageResizer to only work in certain directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33440702/configuring-imageresizer-web-config-to-only-work-on-certain-directories), you cannot make HttpModules location-specific. They are application-wide, always.

By default, ImageResizer doesn't do anything to images unless you specifically request it via the querystring. It does (with authorizeAllImages="true") permit you to control access via `AuthorizeImage`, as well as perform URL rewriting via `Rewrite` and `PostRewrite` events.

If the images are being served from a VirtualPathProvider, it will enable that to work by assigning the request to StaticFileHandler; but if the images are physical files, it does nothing.

If you want true isolation, you can always set up a child app (sub-application) with a separate application pool, mounted in a subdirectory.

Comment: Nathanael, thanks for the response. After configuring some logic in the Rewrite delegate and stepping through, my PostRewrite delegate is still called for every image which negates the point of doing the logic in Rewrite (no images outside of my three specified directories end up in imagecache regardless of the presence of logic in the Rewrite delegate - although that could be simply because they weren't called with modify querystring parameters which I'm not concerned about). Am I missing something here?

Comment: ...Again, I only want images within three specific directories to be processed (enforce watermarking) while every other image elsewhere I want to cut out of the ImageResizer lifecycle as soon as possible (or as efficiently as possible if that is for some reason at a different point).

Comment: Hi Ted; PostRewrite and AuthorizeImage will be called regardless, but by setting process=no and cache=no, you can prevent it from working into those directories (i.e, caching or processing upon request). It's not going to do anything by default.

Comment: So in other words, no way to circumvent the lifecycle sooner/quicker than just not defining settings in general on an image. So unless there's a reason to enforce no further processing (e.g. ensure that ignore any and all ?height=x requests altogether apart from permitted areas), then just don't do anything at all.

Comment: Correct. Events will be fired if an HttpModule is installed.